# How to convert timestamp in seconds with hour offset to local iOS NSDate?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Im trying to convert a timestamp in seconds since 01/01/1970 with an hour timezone offset (i.e. -6) to a local NSDate. Here is what i have so far:

```
    NSInteger startTime = 1312228800;
    NStInteger startTimeOffset = -6;
    NSDate *startTimeDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:startTime];

    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];        

    NSInteger gmtOffset = [startTimeOffset intValue]*60*60;
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:gmtOffset]];        
    NSDate *newStartTimeDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:startTimeDate]];
```

For example if i have the time of 1312228800 i get 08/01/2011 20:00 at GMT 0. The actual startTime is 08/01/2011 14:00 at GMT -6. However locally on the device if i am based in EST the startTime should be set to 08/01/2011 16:00 GMT -4.

However i just get back the same startTime with no offset taken into account which is 08/01/2011 20:00 in the example above.

Any ideas where im going wrong here, have a feeling its got something to do with the setDateFormat: argument?

thx

Comment: What does "startTime" look like before you execute the last statement??

Comment: And what is "startTimeOffset"??

Comment: And if you're ending up with a NSDate object, why do you care about the time zone?  The time zone isn't really supplied until you format -- the TZ inside the NSDate object is just for use by `description`, which should only be used for diagnostic formatting.

Comment: startTime is 1312228800 and startTimeOffset is -6. Have also corrected example above to reflect newStartDate. The reason i am doing this is to try and convert the startTime into an NSDate object that i can save to Core Data. Granted i could do the conversion when i read the date to display it but either way its the same problem?

Comment: Like I said, the time zone in an NSDate object is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to use a formatter?  What about something like this:

```
NSInteger offsetSecs = [startTimeOffset intValue] * 60 * 60;
NSDate *theDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(startTime + offsetSecs)];
```

Comment: Wouldnt that only work if the device/user was in the same timezone as the offset?

Comment: Then to get local time, adjust result above (which is gmt time) using current timezone on phone:       NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    timeZoneOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate]